# Как подключить библиотеку классов в Windows Forms?

Tags: c#

Написал библиотеку для WF в одном проекте и пытаюсь подключить в другой. В ссылках нашёл эту библиотеку и галочку поставил, но всё равно не могу ей пользоваться. При этом прописал using, то есть, проект её видит, но классы не работают

Comment: Классы в библиотеке должны быть `public`.

Comment: Проблема была в другом, но всё равно спасибо!